# PHP Use variable name in foreach after setting value

Tags: php, foreach

EDIT: SOLVED

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I have a foreach loop which creates variables in the form of:

```
    foreach ($fieldsarray as $field)
    {
        ${$field} = $globalrow[$field];
    }
```

This creates variables using array elements, like $firstname, $lastname, etc.

Now, since the values of these variables are fetched from the DB, I cannot use the variable names again in the same foreach. What I would like to do is to use this in the loop:

```
if(!empty($$field)) 
  {
    $r.$field='<tr><td width="50%">'.${$field}._label.': </td>
    <td width="50%">'.${$field}.'</td></tr>';
  }
```

Basically, this would generate table rows with data from DB, but only if the value of the variable is not empty.

My problem is: Since I have declared above that e.g. $firstname = 'John' - then the second part of the code does not work anymore, because I assume PHP does not transform the above snippet into

```
if(!empty($firstname))
```

but rather into

```
if(!empty(John))
```

How can I "force" PHP to again use the variable NAME rather than its value in this case?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: OK, cheezeburgers suggestions worked and I think now it's working as intended. Thanks to all of you for your help.

EDIT 2: The table rows are output correctly on the screen, e.g.:

```
First Name: John
Last Name : Smith
```

but for some weird reason in the email confirmation the output is doubled:

```
First Name: John
Last Name : Smith
First Name: John
Last Name : Smith
```

In both cases I simply echo them with:

```
<?php echo $allrows ?>
```

where $allrows is in the foreach loop.

(I will post this part as a new question since this seems to be a new problem now)

Comment: Urgh, that gives me a headache, variable variables are not easy to read. What are you actually trying to achieve? Im positive there is a much better way

Comment: Why do you need the variable variables? Can't you use the array for table generation? (hint: you can)

Comment: Why don't you just use `if (!empty($globalrow[$field]))`?

Comment: But I think it should work as you wrote it. PHP does transform `empty($$field)` into `empty($firstname)` when `$field = 'firstname'`.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this? You already have a variable (the array) with all the info you need. This makes no sense to me

Comment: @PeeHaa I think you do not understand: Yes I have an array, but the array has variable names as elements, i.e. "firstname", "lastname", etc. The loop then dynamically creates variables from the array and assigns values to them (from the DB). At the same time I need to output table rows (if values in DB not empty) which contain variable labels and values.

Comment: I understand perfectly fine. My question is *why* you need to create the extra variables. This really sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @Al-IskanderAl-Albani Please edit your question with a vardump of $fieldsarray and $globalrow, plus your expected html output. As originally stated im possitive there is a MUCH cleaner way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will work it out fine, just that you have missed the quote around `_label` and probably that's being read as a constant.

Try this:

```
$$field='<tr><td width="50%">'.${$field}.'_label: </td>
<td width="50%">'.${$field}.'</td></tr>';
```

which gives the output as:

```
John_label: John
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/141116)**

Comment: Exactly, but it should not be John_label: John -> I need it to produce $firstname_label: John - because I am declaring the variable $firstname_label in other part of code as $firstname_label = 'First Name'. Do you see my problem now?

Comment: @Al-IskanderAl-Albani You can do that by simply changing `${$field}` to `$field`.

Comment: OK changed that, but its still not outputting anything, because as I said, I think the problem is here: **if(!empty($$field))**

Comment: @Al-IskanderAl-Albani Can you paste the values of `$field` and `$$field`? Echo them right before the if.

Comment: i can echo them, and they output correctly as "firstname" and "John", but the Problem remains with the label thingy. I can either have "firstname_label" or "John_label" - neither will produce anything of course, because the variable is named above as $firstname_label. I can mix it with the string and visually produce "$firstname_label" - but thats just it, it does not get interpreted, its simply output as it is.

Comment: @Al-IskanderAl-Albani That's quite confusing. I thought you wanted to display it that way. Try chaging the `${$field}.'_label:` to `${$field.'_label'}.':`

Answer (score -1):

I would do that differently altogether, but to answer your question, try this:

```
extract($globalrow);
```

It creates variables in the current scope for every entry in the array going by the name of the respective key. So as long as there are no numeric keys, this should work instead of `${$field} = $globalrow[$field];`. Then just refer to the variables by actual name.

http://php.net/extract