# PHP foreach loop output duplicated

Tags: php, foreach, duplicate-data

**SOLVED:**

Had to put an initial value of ' ' for $rfield as hinted by KNaito BEFORE the loop (i.e. $rfield = ' ';).
Thank you!

---

ORIGINAL POST:

As a continuation of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267288/php-use-variable-name-in-foreach-after-setting-value), which was solved, a new problem arises where the output of the foreach loop is duplicated in one instance but not another:

Here is my loop:

```
foreach($fieldsarray as $field) {

${$field} = $globalrow[$field];

if(!empty($$field)) {$rfield.='<tr><td width="50%">'.${$field.'_label'}.': </td><td width="50%">'.${$field}.'</td></tr>';

}
} 

$allrows=$rfield;
```

The $fieldsarray has too many elements to insert here, but it is like this:

```
$fieldsarray = array ('firstname','lastname','email');
```

$globalrow is a mysql query which fetches the data of the logged in user per mysql_fetch_assoc.

The expected HTML output will be a registration confirmation with a summary of the entered data shown on screen and also in the email confirmation which the user receives.

It is a table consisting of rows of the entered data. All data is saved in the DB.

The table rows are output correctly on the screen, e.g.:

```
First Name: John
Last Name : Smith
```

but for some weird reason in the email confirmation **the output is duplicated**:

```
First Name: John
Last Name : Smith
First Name: John
Last Name : Smith
```

In both cases I simply echo them with:

```
<?php echo $allrows ?>
```

As I said, I have read about the problems of duplicate output when using while and foreach with e.g. mysql_fetch_array - but as you can see this is not the case here, and why would this work fine on screen while in the email confirmation all elements are shown twice?

---

**EDIT TO EXPLAIN TO USER COMMENtING BELOW:**

I have a registration Form, where people register (insert personal data). When they fill out the form, they get to the summary page which shows their inserted data, like:

```
Prefix: Mr.
First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
```

After klicking "Submit" - the user is marked as "registered" and he receives an email confirmation.

The Email Confirmation itself is a simple HTML File with the addition of the PHP snippet  which prints the rows with the User Data (exactly as shown on the Summary page).

Now, on the summary page, the output is OK, but in the email confirmation all data is DUPLICATED, and shown, eg. as:

```
Prefix: Mr.
First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
Prefix: Mr.
First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
```

So, why would this happen? Both Summary and Confirmation HTML is absolutely the same code.

EDIT (PRINT_R):

print_r($globalrow):

```
    Array ( [regid] => 630 [eid] => 1 [guid] => xxxxxx-D898-CBE0-D018-xxxxxxx [regcomp] => 1 [regdate] => 2014-04-25 14:57:28 [prefix] => Mr. 
[nametitle] => [firstname] => Xxxxx [lastname] => Xxxxxx [company] => XXXXXXX [department] => [jobtitle] => [street] => XXXXXXXX [zip] => 8217878979 [city] => XXXXX [country] => XXXXX [priv_street] => [priv_zip] => [priv_city] => 
[priv_country] => [phone] => XXXXXX [fax] => [mobile] => [email] => XXXXXXX [travel] => [terms] => [notes] => [accommodation] => [roompartner] => [arrivaldate] => [arrivaltype] => [arrivalairport] => [arrivalflightno] => 
[arrivaltransfer] => [departuredate] => [departuretype] => [departureairport] => [departureflightno] => [departuretransfer] => 
[dinner] => [dinnerpersons] => 0 [food] => [hotel] => [checkin] => [checkout] => [roomtype] => [special] => [hotelnotes] => [groupparticipanttype] => Companion [mainparticipantid] => 629 )
```

print_r($fieldsarray):

```
    Array ( [0] => prefix [1] => nametitle [2] => firstname [3] => lastname [4] => company [5] => department [6] => jobtitle [7] => email 
[8] => phone [9] => fax [10] => mobile [11] => street [12] => zip [13] => city [14] => country [15] => dinner [16] => dinnerpersons 
[17] => food [18] => checkin [19] => checkout [20] => hotel [21] => roomtype [22] => roompartner [23] => special [24] => hotelnotes 
[25] => accommodation [26] => arrivaldate [27] => departuredate [28] => notes [29] => terms )
```

Comment: As i said in your previous question, please just explain what you want to do in simple english. I am absolutely certain that this semi obfuscated  unreadable variable variables is not the answer.

Comment: Try using mysqli or PDO. if that doesn't work, consider cutting your foreach loop, and specifying the index of 0 to specify the first element in the array of users. i.e. `$field[0]['firstname'];`

Comment: instead of `$$` use `extract`

Comment: Ok, so we know what you want to do. Next, what is held in the variables $globalrow and $fieldsarray? If you can show a print_r() of each that would help.

Comment: @user574632 Hello, I have already posted what is in the $fieldsarray -  $fieldsarray = array ('firstname','lastname','email'); And the $globalrow is a mysql_fetch_assoc from the main DB query (select * from main_table where guid = $_GET['guid'])

Comment: I WILL POST THE PRINT_R ABOVE

Comment: The above your code seems to have no problem. Where do you initialize `$rfield`? Is there any possibility that process called twice?